# How to apply time zone on datetime_select in Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timezone

I have a form that looks like

```
= form.datetime_select :due_at
= form.time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones
```

When this object is saved, we need it to apply the time zone that was selected. For example if the user selects "03-01-2013 11:00" and "Central Time (US & Canada)", I want the date/time, in this case 11AM to be as 11AM CST instead of our application default time zone of "Pacific Time (US & Canada)".

This is actually nested within another form so we cannot simply change Time.zone in the controller with an around_filter. We are trying to figure out a solution that works during daylight savings time as well.

Comment: Are `due_at` and `time_zone` both attributes on a model?

Comment: @BenjaminSullivan Yes, in this case `due_at` and `time_zone` are attributes on the model.

Answer (score 3):

If `due_at` and `time_zone` are both attributes of a single model, then you could use a before_save hook to make sure `due_at` is encoded in the time zone of `time_zone` before being  stored in the database.

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :apply_time_zone

  protected

  def apply_time_zone
    self.due_at = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[time_zone].parse "#{due_at_start.to_s(:db)} UTC"
  end
end
```

`ActiveSupport::TimeZone[t].parse(s)` will parse `s` into time zone `t`, and `.to_s(:db)` converts a time to string in UTC.

Comment: Thanks for those edits, I've been writing a lot of javascript recently haha. Did the answer solve your problem?

Comment: Can you refer to source or example where `#to_s(:db)` converts a time to UTC as you stated in your revision? As far as I can tell `#to_s` with `:db` just executes `strftime` without any timezone change. My tests in Rails 2.3 confirm this. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/508f33f35c9ce7a8973c1cf3466223313dfcfb24/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/conversions.rb